# Configure error with Qt, MinGW, CMake: Qt version not found

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, qt-creator, configure

I have a problem building an application from Qt Creator; from the configure step, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1382 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

If I configure it from the command line, everything is file:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  ..\ProjectDir
```

In the paths environment variable Qt is present (src, bin and lib paths).

Platform:
Windows 7
MinGW/GCC 4.4
CMake 2.8.11
Qt 4.8.5
Qt Creator 2.8.1

Comment: Do you have an environment variable QTDIR set to the root folder that contains the Qt bin and include folders? I find this helps on windows where there is no standard location for libraries and include folders.

Comment: Yes, it is already defined.

Comment: Are you getting the same issue without QtCreator, i.e. on the console?

Comment: cmake --trace may be of use here.

Comment: Any progress on this? Is this still unresolved?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: this issue is limited to QtCreator. From the console, with cmake, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to develop a CMake based project with Qt Creator, you should not execute CMake manually before. Qt Creator generates a Code::Blocks project from your source to work with CMake, so if you generate with -G "MinGW Makefiles" it will not work.

Instead, you could try the following steps:

1. In Qt Creator, Open Project > Select the top level CMakeLists.txt
2. Set a build directory somewhere close to the CMakeLists.txt or in its parent folder, then click on Next
3. Select your generator (Combination of a Qt version and a compiler)
4. [optional] set some CMake arguments
5. Click on Execute CMake, then Finish

Your project should now be opened in Qt Creator and ready for development